# Ten bagger baseball explanation

Tags: expressions

Why would a "ten bagger" refer to baseball? Where is the ten involved in it?

Comment: What's the context? I've never heard this before. Only one-bagger, two-bagger, etc., to refer to a single and a double.

Comment: @jackgill: This is an investing term. Speculative investors look to increase their initial investment by a factor of 10, known then as a "ten-bagger". You hear it a lot with day traders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "bagger" is related to farming. You harvest 10 bags of wheat from 1 bag sowed which is analogical to investing.

Comment: Any sources in support?

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_bagger) given in Adel's answer is spot-on, but the additional explanation misses the mark.

Sports (and martial) metaphors are big in the business world. In baseball slang, a "two bagger" is a double and a "three bagger" is a triple. So an investment that doubles your money would be a "two bagger", and one that triples your money would be a "three bagger". By extension, an investment that returns ten times your investment would be a "ten bagger"—even though that's quite impossible in baseball (at least under the current rules).

Comment: ok, so it came from a two bagger, three bagger and four bagger, but more than four is actually not possible in the baseball analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was a new word *based-on* the words "two-bagger", "four-bagger" etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_bagger

Why 10? Hmm, because a ten-fold increase is impressive, and easy to say - monosyllabic. And maybe $10.00 bill is nice.

Comment: That page has been deleted, but [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tenbagger.asp) has an article on ten-baggers.

Answer (score 1):

If each base is a bag, a ten-bagger perhaps refers to how many bags are touched when a grand slam is hit. The batter hits 4 bags, the first base runner 3 bags, etc. Totally 10 bags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).